# Is there a way to encrypt a Hard Disk such that, it is impossible to prove that it is encrypted?

Tags: linux, encryption, disk-encryption

Is there a way to encrypt a Hard Disk such that, it is impossible to prove that it is encrypted?

Say I have an HDD that is encrypted. When fell into the wrong hands or a hacker, is there a way to ensure the hacker thinks it is not encrypted at all, but it is just hard formatted disk (where random digits are written into disk to avoid recovery of data)?

Comment: Nothing in particular. Was thinking how secure is encrypting a disk, if the other person could break your jaw and get your key or password. So in a way encrypting disk seems to give you more of a physical harm than actually securing the data! So the question is - how secure is the data!?

Comment: Can you rewrite your question to be relevant to Linux or Unix specifically. It currently seems more relevant to the fields of cryptography or information security (both topics have separate StackExhange sites).

Comment: Given the answer below, I retract my previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you're referring to plausible deniability, yes.

Both vera-crypt and dmcrypt (cryptsetup) have a mode in which metadata about the encrypted volume is not written to disk; There are no headers of any sort. The end result is a disk with random-looking data written to it.

For more info, see vera-crypt's documentation about [plausible deniability](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Plausible%20Deniability.html) and dmcrypts FAQ on [dm-plain](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/-/wikis/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#2-setup) (scroll down to question 2.4).

Comment: However, when your adversary looks at the disk they will immediately see that it contains seemingly random data and will rightfully assume that this is encrypted content, not actually random bits. They can still break your jaw in an attempt to get a password; if it was indeed random data they won't get a password but you still got a broken jaw.